# How to create progress bar programmatically?

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I created a view with a progress bar with an IBOutlet. Whenever I rotate the view to landscape mode, it is not rotated. So, I need to create the progress bar programmatically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
progressView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,20);
[self.view addSubview:progressView];
```

Should get you started.

I would read up on views and view controllers in Apple's documentation.  The View Programming Guide for iPhone OS goes into quite a bit of detail for what you want to do.  If you have not read the iPhone Application Programming Guide and the iPhone Development Guide I would do so first.

All of these documents are available on developer.apple.com, and also in the help system of Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate the progress bar to vertical by the below code:

`progressView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI * 0.5 );`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the property of size in IB then is't work fine see in below image[image]

this work for both orientations