# Objective-C: Progress view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress

How can I create `progressView` programmatically with height 50 and rounded corners in my Xcode project?

if I use this code

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 3.0f);  
progressView.transform = transform;
```

rounded corners disappear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create progress bar programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617093/how-to-create-progress-bar-programmatically)

Comment: This question not solve my problem. I can’t change height programmatically

Comment: If your problem is that you are not able to change height than you should mention it in your question. how can some one possibly figure that out from the question?

Comment: Check my answer user214155.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried getting progress view with rounded corners.I got it.

First you need to add and import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then

```
UIProgressView *progressView;
progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:187.0/255 green:160.0/255 blue:209.0/255 alpha:1.0];
[[progressView layer]setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 200)];
[[progressView layer]setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[progressView setProgress:(float)(50/100) animated:YES];  ///15

[[progressView layer]setCornerRadius:progressView.frame.size.width / 2];
[[progressView layer]setBorderWidth:3];
[[progressView layer]setMasksToBounds:TRUE];
progressView.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self.view addSubview:progressView];
```

Also

[KAProgressLabel](http://alexiscreuzot.com/KAProgressLabel/)

[Circular Progress View](http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.in/2013/06/custom-circular-progress-view-for-ios.html)

[Progress View Using Bezir Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:whateverStyle]
progressView.progress = 0.75f;
```

//setting height and corner

```
[[UIProgressView appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 50)];
[progressView.layer setCornerRadius:4];
 progressView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
 progressView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;

[self.view addSubview: progressView]
```

Comment: height doesn’t changes

Comment: If you want to change the height then you have to implement it through custom draw method.

Comment: Yes but  rounded corners disappear with your custom draw method

Comment: Here is a third party progress bar that allows setting height. https://github.com/yannickl/YLProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    progressView.progress = 0.75f;
    [progressView.layer setCornerRadius:10];
    progressView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
   progressView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 10.0f);
    progressView.transform = transform;

    [self.view addSubview: progressView];
```